# How to stop/start specfic WebSphere-deployed EAR from command line?

Tags: websphere, ear, application-server

I'm throwing a dependency jar into my exploded EAR on WebSphere app server. I need to stop/start the EAR to get WS to execute the new code. Is there a way to do this from command line?

Answer (score 13):

Try running something like this:

```
/opt/ibm/websphere/appserver/profiles/<MyProfileName>/bin/wsadmin.sh -c "AdminControl.invoke(AdminControl.queryNames('type=ApplicationManager,process=<MyServerName>,*'),'stopApplication','MyAppName')" -lang jython
```

It will prompt you for a WAS Userid and password (in case you have **enabled "Administrative Security"**) and when you enter them - provided your userid has at least been assigned the **Operator** Role - your application will be stopped.

In a similar way you may start the same application.

Comment: What is the Windows/DOS variant for that command? I tried the following in a command prompt but it did not work: `wsadmin -c "AdminControl.invoke(AdminControl.queryNames('type=Applicati‌​onManager,process=<M‌​yServerName>,*'),'st‌​opApplication','MyAp‌​pName')"`

Comment: Run with `wsadmin.bat` and add `-lang jython` in the command line

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manage that using the `wsadmin` command line tool provided as a part of your WAS installation. Pretty much any administration task can be scripted using this tool.

I don't know the specific command to do what you've asked but here is a link to the documentation that should help get you going.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftxml_script.html