# The launch of ear to WebSphere using the command line or bat file

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere

I need to start the ear, specifically the application installed on the WebSphere server and also stop it
I tried to use the information found on here [How to stop/start specfic WebSphere-deployed EAR from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689692/how-to-stop-start-specfic-websphere-deployed-ear-from-command-line) but nothing came of it, other sources I found. I would like to get a more detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

This guide from IBM is pretty straight forward [Starting applications using wsadmin scripting](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/txml_startapplication.html)

So basically run the wsadmin.bat to start the scripting tool and identfy the correct cell/node/server that your application is running on

Comment: Could you give an example please?